# multiple changes in one line with diff tool?

Tags: diff

Normally, 'diff' tool finds only changes between lines. For example, if i compare 'abcdef' and 'AbcdEf', diff will show that 'abcde' is changed and 'f' is unchanged. Is it possible to find multiple changes per line, so in example above i will see that it's only 'a' changed to 'A' and 'e' changed to 'E'? Or diff outut format does not support such?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [showing differences within a line in diff output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342256/showing-differences-within-a-line-in-diff-output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple diff tools that will do what you're asking for.

Off the top of my head I know [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) and [TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) does that.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) which highlights with different colours changes on the same line.

[image]

Comment: screenshot is worth a 1000 words

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool to diff web code regardless of differences from comments and whitespace. This means my tool can diff a completely minified file against a similar beautified file. It is written entirely in JavaScript so you try it directly in your browser without downloading or installing anything.  This does highlight differences per line and highlights differences per characters on those lines.

http://prettydiff.com/