# showing differences within a line in diff output

Tags: diff, patch, word-diff

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265949/multiple-changes-in-one-line-with-diff-tool/1266114#1266114) has an image of KDiff3 highlighting intra-line differences.  Does someone know of a tool which can show the same (ex, via color) on the command line?

Another way to think of this is wanting to diff each difference in a patch file.

Comment: Try [this perl script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight) from the git project. [This blog](https://coderwall.com/p/ydluzg) describes it. See [my gist](https://gist.github.com/unphased/5303697) to see how I set it up (pager section)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/diff-within-a-line

Comment: Ciro: Yup, including my answer: use emacs' ediff mode...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using 'diff' (or anything else) to get character-level diff between text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721738/using-diff-or-anything-else-to-get-character-level-diff-between-text-files)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if this is sufficiently command line for your purpose, but [vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html) can do this (even does colour). See for example the image in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059848/vimdiff-how-to-extract-similar-lines-in-files-and-output-them-to-a-file).

Answer (score 10):

I tried all the tools I found: wdiff, dwdiff, kdiff3, vimdiff to show the difference between two long and slightly different lines. My favourite is `diff-highlight` (part of git contrib)

- it supports diff format - great advantage over tools requiring two files like (dwdiff), e.g. if you need to  visualize the output of unit tests
- it highlights with black+white or with color if you connect it to colordiff
- highlights characterwise - helpful for comparing long lines without spaces (better than wdiff)

### Installation

On Ubuntu, you probably already have it as part of git contrib (installed within the `git` deb package).
Copy or link it into your ~/bin folder from `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight`

### Usage example

```
cat tmp.diff | diff-highlight | colordiff
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another intuitive way to see all word-sized differences (though not side-by-side) is to use `wdiff` together with `colordiff` (you might need to install both). An example of this would be:

```
wdiff -n {file-A} {file-A} | colordiff
```

You can optionally pipe this into `less -R` to scroll through the output (`-R` is used to show the colors in `less`).

Comment: This is the only vim-less solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

`ccdiff` is a convenient dedicated tool for the task. Here is what an example may look like with it:

[image: ccdiff example output]

By default, it highlights the differences in color, but it can be used on a console without color support too.

The package is included in the main repository of Debian:

> ccdiff is a colored diff that also colors inside changed lines.
>
> All command-line tools that show the difference between two files fall short in showing minor changes visuably useful. ccdiff tries to give the look and feel of `diff --color` or `colordiff`, but extending the display of colored output from colored deleted and added lines to colors for deleted and addedd characters within the changed lines.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and wanted to avoid using `vimdiff`. I found [`dwdiff`](http://os.ghalkes.nl/dwdiff.html) (which is available in Debian) to have several advantages over `wdiff`.

The most useful feature of `dwdiff` is that you can customise the delimiters with `-d [CHARS]`, so it's useful for comparing all kinds of output. It also has color built in with the `-c` flag.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [`colordiff`](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) for this.

In their [man page](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/colordiff.html):

> Any options passed to colordiff are
>   passed through to diff except for the
>   colordiff-specific option 'difftype',
>   e.g.
>
> `colordiff --difftype=debdiff file1
>   file2`
>
> Valid values for 'difftype' are: diff,
>   diffc, diffu, diffy, wdiff, debdiff;
>   these correspond to plain diffs,
>   context diffs, unified diffs,
>   side-by-side diffs, wdiff output and
>   debdiff output respectively. Use these
>   overrides when colordiff is not able
>   to determine the diff-type
>   automatically.

I haven't tested it, but the side-by-side output (as produced by `diff -y file1 file2`) might give you the equivalent of in-line differences.

Comment: You can also pipe diff output into colordiff, but I confirm that it doesn't work