# Using 'diff' (or anything else) to get character-level diff between text files

Tags: text, command-line, diff

I'd like to use 'diff' to get a both line difference between and character difference.
For example, consider:

**File 1**

```
abcde
abc
abcccd
```

**File 2**

```
abcde
ab
abccc
```

Using **diff -u** I get:

```
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 abcde
-abc
-abcccd
\ No newline at end of file
+ab
+abccc
\ No newline at end of file
```

However, it only shows me that were changes in these lines. What I'd like to see is something like:

```
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 abcde
-ab<ins>c</ins>
-abccc<ins>d</ins>
\ No newline at end of file
+ab
+abccc
\ No newline at end of file
```

You get my drift.

Now, I know I can use [other engines](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) to mark/check the difference on a specific line. But I'd rather use one tool that does all of it.

Comment: per char diff is especially useful when it comes to CJK texts, where no whitespace is aplied for word splitting.

Answer (score 130):

Git has a word diff, and defining all characters as words effectively gives you a character diff. However, newline changes are **ignored**.

#### Example

Create a repository like this:

```bash
mkdir chardifftest
cd chardifftest
git init
echo -e 'foobarbaz\ncatdog\nfox' > file
git add -A; git commit -m 1
echo -e 'fuobArbas\ncat\ndogfox' > file
git add -A; git commit -m 2
```

Now, do `git diff --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. master^ master` and you'll get:

[image: git diff]

Note how both additions and deletions are recognized at the character level, while both additions and deletions of newlines are ignored.

You may also want to try one of these:

```bash
git diff --word-diff=plain --word-diff-regex=. master^ master
git diff --word-diff=porcelain --word-diff-regex=. master^ master
```

Comment: You don't need to create a repo at all, you can simply give git diff any two files, anywhere on your filesystem and it works. Your command works great for me in that way, so thanks! `git diff --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. file1 file2`

Comment: This is profoundly helpful! Would +1 once as a software developer and +1 twice more as an author/writer if I could. Unlike in code, where lines tend to be reasonably short, when writing papers/stories, each paragraph tends to take the form of a long word-wrapped line, and this feature makes the diffs actually visually useful.

Comment: I needed to add `--no-index` to@qwertzguys' response above in order to get it to work for me outside of a git repo.

So: `git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. file1 file2`

Comment: git diff doesn't work in general setting:  git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. <(echo string1) <(echo string2)  .. Nothing, but this works:  diff --color  <(echo string1) <(echo string2).

Comment: @NathanBell I needed to add `--no-index` inside of a repo too

Comment: For a slightly more compact command `--word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=.` can be replaced with `--color-words=.`

Comment: This worked pretty well for me except for the colors (regular text was bright green while inserted text was slightly darker green). I discovered, however, you can temporarily change colors by passing an argument via -c eg: `git -c color.diff.new="cyan bold" diff --color-words=. <file1> <file2>` shows all additions in bold cyan.

Comment: --no-index is the way

Comment: @mtraceur "when writing papers/stories, each paragraph tends to take the form of a long word-wrapped line" related: [merge that works at word granularity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/merge-that-works-at-word-granularity-instead-of-line)

Answer (score 55):

You can use:

```
diff -u f1 f2 |colordiff |diff-highlight
```

[image: screenshot]

`colordiff` is a Ubuntu package. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install colordiff`.

`diff-highlight` is from git (since version 2.9). It is located in `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight`. You can put it somewhere in your `$PATH`.

Comment: colordiff is also available on homebrew for Mac: `brew install colordiff`

Comment: On Mac you can find `diff-highlight` in `$(brew --prefix git)/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight`

Comment: In case you didn't install git using brew - `diff-highlight` can also be installed with python's pip - `pip install diff-highlight` (I prefer it even if git is installed via brew)

Comment: You actually can skip the first diff step for what its worth `colordiff -u file1 file2  | diff-highlight` works for me

Comment: Fantastic just what I needed.

Answer (score 29):

Python's [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) is ace if you want to do this programmatically.  For interactive use, I use [vim's](http://www.vim.org/) diff mode (easy enough to use: just invoke vim with `vimdiff a b`).  I also occasionally use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), which does pretty much everything you could hope for from a diff tool.

I haven't see any command line tool which does this usefully, but as Will notes, the difflib example code might help.

Comment: Oh.. I was hoping for a something more standardized (like a hidden command line argument). The damnest thing is that I have Beyond Compare 2 and it even supports text output to file/console of the diff but it still only includes line-diffs and not char-diffs.

I'll look into python if no one has anything else.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to vimdiff.  I found the default colors to be unreadable, but found a solution for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019281/load-different-colorscheme-when-using-vimdiff.

Answer (score 20):

As one [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721738/using-diff-or-anything-else-to-get-character-level-diff-between-text-files?answertab=trending#comment63451922_31356602) to main answer said you don't have to commit to use git diff:

```
git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. file1 file2
```

[image]

green would be the character that is added by the second file.

red would be the character that is added by the first file.

Comment: Yep, this is the best answer (as of today at least), given that it's the easiest to get on any system (`git` is fully cross-platform, and everyone has it on their computer nowadays) and the easiest to use, by far.

Comment: You may need to include `--no-index` to make it actually work, as commented on main answer

Comment: @PauloFreitas actually I had it in the screenshot but somehow I missed it in the command thanks for pointing out, edited

Comment: If you want to pipe this to `less` you can use `less -R` to keep the colors

Comment: I've had `alias gitdiff="git diff --no-index --word-colors=."` in my bashrc for a while now :D It's a beautiful, easy-to-read diff, especially if you have a bunch of huge XML / JSON files with all of the newlines removed :')

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `cmp` command in Solaris:

> `cmp`
>
> Compare two files, and if they differ, tells the first byte and line number where they differ.

Comment: `cmp` is also available on (at least some) Linux distributions.

Comment: It's also available on Mac OS X.

Comment: Characters can consist of multiple bytes, and OP asked for a visual comparison.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: cmp allows visual comparison, with flag `-l -b`.

Comment: `cmp` exits after the first difference

Comment: `cmp -l` shows *every* byte that is different, but I was expecting it to work like `git diff --word-regex=.`, where if you delete a single character, it only shows 1 character as being different. Instead, `cmp` will show *every* character after that as different since the files are then misaligned. Just in case that saves anyone else the ~15-20 minutes it took me to realize that :P

Answer (score 12):

Python has convenient library named `difflib` which might help answer your question.

Below are two oneliners using `difflib` for different python versions.

```bash
python3 -c 'import difflib, sys; \
  print("".join( \
    difflib.ndiff( \ 
      open(sys.argv[1]).readlines(),open(sys.argv[2]).readlines())))'
python2 -c 'import difflib, sys; \
  print "".join( \
    difflib.ndiff( \
      open(sys.argv[1]).readlines(), open(sys.argv[2]).readlines()))'
```

These might come in handy as a shell alias which is easier to move around with your `.${SHELL_NAME}rc`.

```bash
$ alias char_diff="python2 -c 'import difflib, sys; print \"\".join(difflib.ndiff(open(sys.argv[1]).readlines(), open(sys.argv[2]).readlines()))'"
$ char_diff old_file new_file
```

And more readable version to put in a standalone file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import with_statement

import difflib
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as old_f, open(sys.argv[2]) as new_f:
    old_lines, new_lines = old_f.readlines(), new_f.readlines()
diff = difflib.ndiff(old_lines, new_lines)
print ''.join(diff)
```

Comment: Excellent one liners. Would be nice to have a condensed output that ignores unchanged lines.

Answer (score 7):

```
cmp -l file1 file2 | wc
```

Worked well for me. The leftmost number of the result indicates the number of characters that differ.

Comment: Or to just get the leftmost number: `cmp -l file1 file2 | wc -l`

Answer (score 7):

**Coloured, *character-level* `diff` ouput**

Here's what you can do with the the below script and [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight) (which is part of git):

[image: Coloured diff screenshot]

```bash
#!/bin/sh -eu

# Use diff-highlight to show word-level differences

diff -U3 --minimal "$@" |
  sed 's/^-/\x1b[1;31m-/;s/^+/\x1b[1;32m+/;s/^@/\x1b[1;34m@/;s/$/\x1b[0m/' |
  diff-highlight
```

<sub>(Credit to [@retracile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865578/5353461) for the `sed` highlighting)</sub>

Comment: It shows good diff on shell screen, but how do I see that diff in GVim??

Comment: What that's really a gvim question :). `command | gvim -` will do what you want.

Comment: For reference diff-highlight appears to be included as part of `git` but not placed on your path. One my machine this lives at `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight`.

Comment: broken link.  How do I install diff-highlight.  Doesn't seem to be in a package manager.

Answer (score 5):

I also wrote my [own script](https://github.com/JEdward7777/JLDiff/blob/master/JLDiff.py) to solve this problem using the [Longest common subsequence algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

It is executed as such

`JLDiff.py a.txt b.txt out.html`

The result is in html with red and green coloring.  Larger files do exponentually take a longer amount of time to process but this does a true character by character comparison without checking line by line first.

Comment: I have found that JLDiff runs a lot faster under pypy.

Answer (score 5):

[ccdiff](https://github.com/Tux/App-ccdiff) is a convenient dedicated tool for the task. Here is what your example looks like with it:

[image: ccdiff example output]

By default, it highlights the differences in color, but it can be used in a console without color support too.

The package is included in the [main repository of Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ccdiff):

> ccdiff is a colored diff that also colors inside changed lines.
>
> All command-line tools that show the difference between two files fall short in showing minor changes visuably useful. ccdiff tries to give the look and feel of `diff --color` or `colordiff`, but extending the display of colored output from colored deleted and added lines to colors for deleted and addedd characters within the changed lines.

Comment: looks nice, but lacking proper install instructions for non-Debian systems.

Comment: @xeruf (**a**) Download the tagged released version's `.tar.gz` file; (**b**) Untar the downloaded file with `tar -xzf *.tar.gz`; (**c**) Move & rename the extracted folder as `/opt/ccdiff`; (**d**) Add symbolic link to the executable in that folder inside some system folders with `ln -s /opt/ccdiff/ccdiff /usr/local/bin/ccdiff`; (**e**) can call it with `ccdiff`.

Answer (score 4):

Python's difflib can do this.

The documentation includes an example [command-line program](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#a-command-line-interface-to-difflib) for you.

The exact format is not as you specified, but it would be straightforward to either parse the ndiff-style output or to modify the example program to generate your notation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. I was hoping for a something more standardized (like a hidden command line argument). But it might do fine still.

I'll look into python if no one has anything more standard (though it seems like not).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an online text comparison tool: 
http://text-compare.com/

It can highlight every single char that is different and continues compare the rest.

Comment: This appears to do line-level diffs with no option for single characters. How do you get it to compare characters?

Comment: Ah; it highlights characters which are different. But it's still line-level in that `catdog` and `cat\ndog` will only match on `cat`

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but if `cmp -l`'s output is not clear enough, you can use:

```bash
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' file1 > file1.vertical
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' file2 > file2.vertical
diff file1.vertical file2.vertical
```

Comment: on OSX use
```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\'$'\n/g' file1 > file1.vertical
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\'$'\n/g' file2 > file2.vertical
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your files in Git, you can diff between versions with the [diff-highlight script](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight), which will show different lines, with differences highlighted.

Unfortunately it only works when the number of lines removed matches the number of lines added - there is stub code for when lines don't match, so presumably this could be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpler solution is always a good solution.
In my case, the below code helps me a lot. I hope it helps
anybody else.

```py
#!/bin/env python

def readfile( fileName ):
    f = open( fileName )
    c = f.read()
    f.close()
    return c

def diff( s1, s2 ):
    counter=0
    for ch1, ch2 in zip( s1, s2 ):
        if not ch1 == ch2:
            break
        counter+=1
    return counter < len( s1 ) and counter or -1

import sys

f1 = readfile( sys.argv[1] )
f2 = readfile( sys.argv[2] )
pos = diff( f1, f2 )
end = pos+200

if pos >= 0:
    print "Different at:", pos
    print ">", f1[pos:end]
    print "<", f2[pos:end]
```

You can compare two files with the following syntax at your favorite terminal:

```
$ ./diff.py fileNumber1 fileNumber2
```

Comment: "I think the simpler solution is always a good solution" and yet your answer is the most complicated out of them all, doesn't use color highlighting for easy visualisation and only prints the position of the first diverging character. It does not answer the question which is about getting a **diff**, i.e. being able to find and see differences between the strings. What you made is simply an equality comparison function (and not even machine-usable since you don't send a non-null exit code in case of inequality).

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers mention using of [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight), a Perl module. But I didn't want to figure out how to install a Perl module. So I made a few minor changes to it to be a self-contained Perl script.

You can install it using:

```
▶ curl -o /usr/local/bin/DiffHighlight.pl \
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexharv074/scripts/master/DiffHighlight.pl
```

And the usage (if you have the Ubuntu `colordiff` mentioned in zhanxw's answer):

```
▶ diff -u f1 f2 | colordiff | DiffHighlight.pl
```

And the usage (if you don't):

```
▶ diff -u f1 f2 | DiffHighlight.pl
```