# How do I allow syntax highlighting to override the color scheme in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am currently using the following lines from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17183382/391161) in my .vimrc to fix my colorscheme when using vimdiff:

```
highlight DiffAdd    cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=17 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
highlight DiffDelete cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=17 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
highlight DiffChange cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=17 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
highlight DiffText   cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=88 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
```

This works great for ordinary text file diffs. Unfortunately, when this is enabled and I diff two java files, the lines that are added (in the diff) lose their syntax highlighting.

Is there a way to make syntax highlighting run *after* the lines above, so that I can git reasonable diff highlighting while preserving syntax highlighting?

Comment: Do you need backlighting all the time or just for comparison?
[https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files)

Comment: Only for comparisons.