# Approximate text matching

Tags: algorithm, text, pattern-matching, ocr

I need to compare two pieces of text, say 200 words long. As these were obtained by OCR, discrepancies can arise at two levels:

- words can be misspelled,
- whole words can be missing or merged, or extra parasitic chunks inserted (in extreme cases, groups of words could be swapped).

The output of the recognition would be a similarity score. I don't think that matching the whole text as a long string can be efficient enough.

Are you aware of methods that specifically address this problem (two-level Levenshtein ??). Are there libraries available ?

(I am not looking for an OCR package.)

Comment: Cross-posted on Mathematics

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721738/using-diff-or-anything-else-to-get-character-level-diff-between-text-files

Comment: May be you want to implement 2 level Levenshtein. 1. word level then 2. character level for identified words.

Comment: @ArunKumar: do you have any reference ?